# Entity Framework Core Insert multiple entities similar to SQL single insert statement

Tags: performance, entity-framework-core

How do you manage to get the same effect as SQL simple

```
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (X), (Y), (Z),.....
```

and so on?

Comment: Maybe you could put the focus of the question on the performance of the operation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may generate the query and execute the same as per the following;

```
DatabaseContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(yourQuery);
```

Refer documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.database.executesqlcommand?view=entity-framework-6.2.0). Even though it is relevant to EF, it is applicable to EF Core as well

Comment: Just out of curiosity - if you do such things directly via SQL-Commands is it then saved instantly? Doesn't that end up in hard to read code? It is not a criticism or anything else - I just want to learn something new and put it into the right corner of my mind. ;)

Comment: Yes you're right. This should be only used to improve performance

Answer (score 1):

If you are using EF Core with SQL Server and has to insert a lot of entities then you can pick one of the following libs that are using [SqlBulkCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy):

- [EFCore.BulkExtensions](https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions)
- [Thinktecture.EntityFrameworkCore](https://dev.azure.com/pawelgerr/Thinktecture.EntityFrameworkCore/_wiki/wikis/Thinktecture.EntityFrameworkCore.wiki?pagePath=%2FPerformance%2FBulk%252DInsert%20(into%20real%252D%20and%20%20temp%252Dtables)&wikiVersion=GBwikiMaster&pageId=2)

The usage is very easy

```
List<MyEntity> entities = ...;

await context.BulkInsertAsync(entities);
```

[SqlBulkCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy) is the fastest way to get the entities into a SQL Server.

> Please note, as with raw SQL statements the `DbContext`is not aware of this operations, so some caution is required. But, if you have to insert a lot of data then there is not much choice as to use some techniques that are closer to the database.

Comment: Thanks, this is probably what i was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

```
var entityList = new List<Entity>();

entityList = {
   new Entity { Property1 = Value, Property2 = "Value"},
   new Entity { Property1 = Value, Property2 = "Value"}
}

context.AddRange(entityList); //Add() for single entity
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: doesn't this execute several round trips?

Comment: At the ```SaveChanges()``` of course - at the ```AddRanges()``` DetectChanges will be called only once.